# How to enable observability for NebulaGraph in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nebula-graph

I would like to study how to enable grafana to monitor the metrics of NebulaGraph on AWS, I walked through https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-vesoft-nebula-graph-cloud/ and https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-vesoft-nebula-graph-cloud/ but still could not find clues on how to do it.

I noticed there is NebulaGraph Dashboard out there, but our monitoring infra are grafana based, could I wire them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience, if you already have a solution with Grafana and probably Prometheus, you can use the NebulaGraph tool [stats-exporter](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-stats-exporter) to export the monitoring metrics into your system. You can click the link to find the instructions in the README.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this seems to be the way to go with, I can reuse what dashboard(prometheus and the node/nebulagraph exporter), and wire them to our grafana then.